# Spring Boot OAuth2 and Oracle IDCS: JWK Set URI responds with 401 UNAUTHORIZED, needs the token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating an **OpenID/OAuth2** client for `Oracle IDCS`. At first, I tested my Spring-Boot configuration with Google and GitHub, and it worked just fine. However, when I was trying to integrate with `Oracle IDCS`, I was receiving `401 Unauthorized` when the application tries to get the signing keys from JWK Set URI (https://idcs-XXXXXXXXX.identity.oraclecloud.com/admin/v1/SigningCert/jwk). I learned that Oracle IDCS JWK Set URI requires the token in the header (`Authorization: Bearer <Access Token Value>`). This is not the case with Google and GitHub.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: "console"
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: "create-drop"
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          oracle:
            client-id: XXXXXX
            client-secret: XXXXXX
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/oracle"
            scope: openid
            client-name: Oracle
            provider: oracle
        provider:
          oracle:
            authorization-uri: "https://idcs-XXXXXXXXX.identity.oraclecloud.com/oauth2/v1/authorize"
            token-uri: "https://idcs-XXXXXXXXX.identity.oraclecloud.com/oauth2/v1/token"
            user-info-uri: "https://idcs-XXXXXXXXX.identity.oraclecloud.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
            jwk-set-uri: "https://idcs-XXXXXXXXX.identity.oraclecloud.com/admin/v1/SigningCert/jwk"
            token-info-uri: "https://idcs-XXXXXXXXX.identity.oraclecloud.com/oauth2/v1/introspect"
            user-name-attribute: name
  profiles:
    active: "@spring.profiles.active@"
```

**snippet from `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder`**

```
private static class RestOperationsResourceRetriever implements ResourceRetriever {
    private static final MediaType APPLICATION_JWK_SET_JSON = new MediaType("application", "jwk-set+json");
        private final RestOperations restOperations;

        RestOperationsResourceRetriever(RestOperations restOperations) {
            Assert.notNull(restOperations, "restOperations cannot be null");
            this.restOperations = restOperations;
        }

        @Override
        public Resource retrieveResource(URL url) throws IOException {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_JWK_SET_JSON));

            ResponseEntity<String> response;
            try {
                RequestEntity<Void> request = new RequestEntity<>(headers, HttpMethod.GET, url.toURI());
                response = this.restOperations.exchange(request, String.class);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new IOException(ex);
            }

            if (response.getStatusCodeValue() != 200) {
                throw new IOException(response.toString());
            }

            return new Resource(response.getBody(), "UTF-8");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Manually sending an HTTP GET request with the token to JWK Set URI gives me the keys.

`curl -v -k -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXX" https://idcs-XXXXXXXXX.identity.oraclecloud.com/admin/v1/SigningCert/jwk`

```
{
    "keys":[
        {
            "kty":"RSA",
            "x5t#S256":"XXXX",
            "e":"XXXX",
            "x5t":"XXXX",
            "kid":"SIGNING_KEY",
            "x5c":[
                "XXXX",
                "XXXX"

            ],
            "key_ops":[
                "encrypt",
                "verify"

            ],
            "alg":"RS256",
            "n":"XXXX"

        }
    ]
}
```

How do I go about including the token in the HTTP GET request header to JWK Set URI?

Is there a way in Spring Boot OAuth2 client to manually set the signing keys? The configuration detailed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-resource-server-jwt-single-key) does not work.

Comment: Hello, did you get this resolved, i am also facing a similar issue where jwks uri is protected.
Between, how did you try Google as OP public network or from VPN?

Comment: I have not resolved this yet. I'm working on this on and off and I will make sure to reply when I resolved it.

Comment: Is there any doc to use spring security with IDCS?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue ? going through the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on "IDCS -> Settings -> Default Settings -> Access Signing Certificate" to configure whether clients can access the signing certificate for the identity domain without logging in to Oracle Identity Cloud Service.

[image]

Comment: We have several other applications in our instance and I am not sure if our IDCS admin will agree to disable this.

The signing keys provided by the JWKS URI can be accessed by supplying the auth bearer token. Spring Security does not supply the auth bearer token by default. I am hoping Spring Security can fix this.

Comment: It's only a public key there.